# Keep stopwords in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

I'm using Elastic's stopword dictionary and it removed the word "No" making the query "No sugar" match for "Sugar".

I was curious if I can override this behavior without modifying the existing stopword dictionary.

Also different approaches are always welcome.

Comment: your question is too broad. if you search for sugar in a field with content no sugar and keyword datatype, you need to remove the no token, but you will retrieve it only if there aren't other words in content. but if you search for "sugar" token in a text datatype without inserting stopword, you will retrieve the doc, without problems. Stopwords need for a different usage. What are you talking about?

Comment: Specify a separate analyzer (standard doesn't use stop words by default) for the query if you do not want to change the field analyzer. Most probably this will have to be a phrase query then.